# antd.customize.less trouble with font-family (help please)

Tags: less, antd, font-family

Hi I have a trouble with changing font-family. I have local font I need to use it. But is doesn't work, what I missing?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you added an additional `:` after `@font-face`. You should use it like this:

```
 @font-face { 
   font-family: 'font-name';
    src: url('url');
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Thank you made my day! You are right! But after this trouble font's in my projec still "font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'Noto Sans', sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Noto Color Emoji';"